# How to display 0.0 instead of .0 in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

In Crystal Reports, when a number is formatted to display some number of decimals, and the number is zero, it doesn't display the 0 in front of the decimal place.

For example, it'll display `.0` for one decimal place instead of `0.0`

How do I get a single leading zero to display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you have unchecked the "Leading zero" setting in format editor.

[image]

Adam (APB Reports)

Comment: Thanks! That looks to be the case. It had been set to unchecked in my global Options, but I rarely go into the "Custom Style" options for Numeric fields, so I didn't remember about that option.

Comment: A pleasure. Not sure why anyone would want to uncheck that setting ;)